Examples of Functionals in the Dual Space of $B(H)$ Outside the Predual
I'm trying to get a better hold of the dual space $B(H)^*,$ but I'm really struggling to find any intuition at all about it. Could someone give some examples of elements in $B(H)^*$ which are not also in $B(H)_*,$ or point me to a reference of such? Preferably for the case $H$ is separable.

Proving the existence of such a linear functional necessarily uses the axiom of choice, so there’s really no “explicit” example of such a thing. But here is a way to “sort of” construct one:
Let $c \subset B(\ell^2)$ be the $C^\ast$-subalgebra consisting of diagonal operators whose diagonal entries have a limit as $n \to \infty$. Let $\varphi: c \to \mathbb{C}$ be the state given by,
$$\varphi(\text{diag}(x_n)) = \lim_n x_n$$
Then by the usual Hahn-Banach argument, $\varphi$ has an extension to a state on $B(H)$, which we shall still denote by $\varphi$. $\varphi$ cannot be normal. Indeed,
$$\text{diag}(1, 1, \cdots, 1, 0, 0, \cdots) \to 1 \text{ in the }\sigma\text{-weak topology as }n \to \infty$$
where in the LHS $1$ appears $n$ times. However,
$$\varphi(\text{diag}(1, 1, \cdots, 1, 0, 0, \cdots)) = 0 \not\to 1 = \varphi(1)$$

Why does it necessarily use the axiom of choice?

@MilesGould If one has a non-normal state on $B(\ell^2)$, then restricting it to diagonal operators yields an element of $(\ell^\infty)^\ast$ that is not in $\ell^1$. The existence of such an element is independent from ZF, see https://mathoverflow.net/a/5477/504602.

One way to construct lots and lots of such functionals is to look at the Calkin algebra $C(H)=B(H)/K(H)$. As with any C$^*$-algebra its state space separates points. As $C(H)$ contains uncountably many pairwise orthogonal projections even when $H$ is separable, it contains a copy of $\ell^\infty(\mathbb R)$. This subalgebra has uncountably many characters $\varphi_t$, $t\in\mathbb R$, where $\varphi_t$ is the evaluation at $t$, and these can be extended to states on $C(H)$ by Hahn-Banach (and the fact that positive linear functionals are characterized by attaining their norm at the identity).
Now given any  $\varphi_t:C(H)\to\mathbb C$, if $q:B(H)\to C(H)$ is the quotient map, we get a state $\tilde\varphi_t=\varphi_t\circ q$ on $B(H)$. Since $q$ maps $K(H)$ to $0$, $\tilde\varphi_t(K)=0$ for all compact $K\in K(H)$. Such a state cannot be normal, since $K(H)$ is $\sigma$-weakly dense in $B(H)$. So the uncountable family of states $\{\tilde\varphi_t\}$ is in $B(H)^*\setminus B(H)_*$.
